# How to prevent Duplicate Mobile Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

My client is syncing Sales cloud data into Marketing using Connect. Obviously, it instantly creates contact with mobile and email addresses associated with one contact. At the same time, we are capturing mobile contact consent via the website. So users text a keyword to a shortcode and we know nothing else about them yet and I believe in this case MC will trigger a Welcome msg from shortcode and add as a NEW contact?

If that's the case then now I have two contacts one came from MobileStudio where let's say the mobile number is 123456 and another contact came from Sales Cloud which already exists with a mobile number 123456.

Is there a way before MC adding him as a new mobile contact which came from TEXT msg it can check if any contact with the same mobile number already exist, so it will not create a new contact?

Comment: No. The operation of an MO message is to create a new contact with the contact key being the mobile number. Creating a new contact/lead in Sales Cloud generates a new contact with a Sales Cloud record id as the contact key.